# How to allow screen.getByText() to fail in jest + react test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, automated-tests, ts-jest

I have a testcase. This project is using `@testing-library/react`

```
it('renders content if loading is false', async () => {
    await waitFor(() => {
      render(<Loader loading={false}><span>foo</span></Loader>);
    });
    const loaderElementText = screen.getByText('Loading');
    expect(loaderElementText).not.toBeInTheDocument();
    const contentText = screen.getByText('foo');
    expect(contentText).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

It does not allow me to run the line `expect(loaderElementText).not.toBeInTheDocument();` with the following error:

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: Loading. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.
```

The inverse testcase, with `loading={true}` works as expected.

I'm at my wits end. What is the syntax to query the document for an element, and expect that the element is not found?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Posting the answer for those curious: use `screen.queryByText()`, which returns null on failure instead of throwing a runtime error.